# Firebase email authentication in Ionic 2 failing in device

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I have tried the firebase email authentication with an ionic 2 app. The authentication is working in the browser with 'ionic serve' but not on the device.

I can create new users and login in the browser and nothing is working on the device.

I have an auth-data provider with the following function:

```
loginUser(email: string, password: string): any {
    return this.fireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}
```

And calling this function from login.ts

```
loginUser() {
        //Call to  AuthData service to login the user
        this.authData.loginUser(this.loginForm.value.email, this.loginForm.value.password).then( authData => {

            //User is authenticated and navigates to homePage
            this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
        })
}
```

I'm getting this alert on device:
*"A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."*

Any idea on what's going on?

Comment: After some testing, It's not related to the code. It has to do with config files but I'm not sure which one.

Answer (score 1):

Please install cordova whitelist plugin by

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist`

and add the following line to src/config.xml

`<allow-intent href="https://*.firebaseio.com"/>`